# Oracle apex 5.1 change user password with pl/sql

Tags: authentication, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm wondering how you change user passwords in oracle apex. Currently I'm trying to use this pl/sql code in a process when the user exists and the reset password field is filled in.

```
if APEX_UTIL.GET_USERNAME(p_userid => :P5_ID) IS NOT NULL AND :P5_WACHTWOORD IS NOT NULL
then
    apex_util.edit_user(
        p_user_id => &P5_ID.,
        p_new_password => '&P5_WACHTWOORD.'
    );
end if;
```

But apex keeps giving me this error: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EDIT_USER'.`

I tried adding the old password in the `p_web_password` param incase apex needed this. I still got the same error.

Just incase I'm doing it completely wrong. I just started using apex and I'm trying to use the default authentication, but I also want to store more stuff about the same user in my own database.

I decided to use the `userid` my database generates as the apex `userid` so I can keep track which user is logged in. Is this the right way or are there better options out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cursory glance at the documentation for the API shows the p_user_name is also a mandatory input.

```
    APEX_UTIL.EDIT_USER (
        p_user_id                      IN                   NUMBER,
        p_user_name                    IN                   VARCHAR2,
        p_first_name                   IN                   VARCHAR2    DEFAULT NULL,
        p_last_name                    IN                   VARCHAR2    DEFAULT NULL,
        p_web_password                 IN                   VARCHAR2    DEFAULT NULL,
...
```

http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/EDIT_USER-Procedure.htm#AEAPI117

Is there any reason you aren't using bind variables for the actual parameter values?

```
p_user_id => :P5_ID
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I didn't notice the default values at all. I switched up between :P5_ID and &P5_ID. when adding a user and finally got it to work with the last one and decided not to change it anymore. Thats the only reason why I'm not using :P5_ID

Comment: Please default with using bind variables, leave &P1_ITEM. syntax for HTML, which even then can be escaped now with &P1_ITEM!HTML.
Use only bind variables for SQL http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2012/02/apex-variables-in-sql.html Good security/performance habits IMHO